# Magento 2 --Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved

Tags: magento2

After Migration, when I try to open a order in admin, it shows this error.
"Order View
Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving."

in M1 site, payment method was paypal and Saved CC.